# I need help with eclipse's configuration

Tags: eclipse

I would like to know why the bin folder does not display under my eclipse projects?

Answer (score 3):

the package explorer view automatically filter the bin folder and, in general, the output folder of the java compilation defined in the buildpath properties.
if you change the view you use (i.e using the navigator view) all the folders are displayed

Comment: @Anzo31 -- If this answers your question, you should accept this answer with the checkbox.